# Ctrl+Wheel to increase font size in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, shortcut

I use **Texmaker**, and I'd like to increase/decrease font size using the `ctrl + mouse wheel` as in TeXStudio. Is there a setting to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: You question is tagged with texstudio, you talk about texmaker, can you please clarify?

Comment: @samcarter That was a mistake, because I mentioned TeXStudio in the question. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @padawan you mentioned texlive in the question, not texstudio.

Comment: @padawan But back to topic: Any reason not to switch to texstudio if this can do what you want?

Comment: @samcarter It is more of a personal issue. I try not to get very used to some environment. So, when I use a tool frequently (in this case LaTeX editor), I try to switch it once in a while and see if there is a more convenient tool.

Comment: did you mean "as in texstudio" (as otherwise I can not guess what you mean by "as in texlive" I don't know any programs in texlive that use the mouse.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OMG this question is a mess! Sorry for that, and thank you!

Comment: My guess would be that if this doesn't work out of the box, then your only option would be to contact the maintainer (http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html#contact) and make a feature request, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: I use Texmaker for years now and didn't find the feature so far...see my first comment above. You can set the font size (static) in the options.